# Custom Pull to refresh in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uirefreshcontrol

I am using a custom spinning wheel class and want to use it as a `UIRefreshControl` but cannot quite figure it out. The custom loading indicator is showing, but the default one is as well (see below), how can I use this class as the only pull to refresh?

[image]

```
let loadingIndicator: ProgressView = {
        let progress = ProgressView(colors: [.green], lineWidth: 5)
        progress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return progress
 }()


func setupRefreshControl(){
        refreshControl.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        setupLoadingIndicator()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(forceRefreshGames), for: .valueChanged)
    }
```

Setting the loading indicator to start:

```
func setupLoadingIndicator(){
        loadingIndicator.isAnimating = true
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            loadingIndicator.centerXAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerXAnchor),
            loadingIndicator.centerYAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor),
            loadingIndicator.widthAnchor
                .constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            loadingIndicator.heightAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: self.loadingIndicator.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Here's the custom class:

```
class ProgressView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: - Initialization
    init(frame: CGRect,
         colors: [UIColor],
         lineWidth: CGFloat
    ) {
        self.colors = colors
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    convenience init(colors: [UIColor], lineWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: .zero, colors: colors, lineWidth: lineWidth)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) is not supported")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn:
            CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: self.bounds.width,
                height: self.bounds.width
            )
        )
        
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
    
    // MARK: - Animations
    func animateStroke() {
        
        let startAnimation = StrokeAnimation(
            type: .start,
            beginTime: 0.25,
            fromValue: 0.0,
            toValue: 1.0,
            duration: 0.75
        )
        
        let endAnimation = StrokeAnimation(
            type: .end,
            fromValue: 0.0,
            toValue: 1.0,
            duration: 0.75
        )
        
        let strokeAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        strokeAnimationGroup.duration = 1
        strokeAnimationGroup.repeatDuration = .infinity
        strokeAnimationGroup.animations = [startAnimation, endAnimation]
        
        shapeLayer.add(strokeAnimationGroup, forKey: nil)
        
        let colorAnimation = StrokeColorAnimation(
            colors: colors.map { $0.cgColor },
            duration: strokeAnimationGroup.duration * Double(colors.count)
        )

        shapeLayer.add(colorAnimation, forKey: nil)
        
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    
    func animateRotation() {
        let rotationAnimation = RotationAnimation(
            direction: .z,
            fromValue: 0,
            toValue: CGFloat.pi * 2,
            duration: 2,
            repeatCount: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        )
        
        self.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    let colors: [UIColor]
    let lineWidth: CGFloat
    
    private lazy var shapeLayer: ProgressShapeLayer = {
        return ProgressShapeLayer(strokeColor: colors.first!, lineWidth: lineWidth)
    }()
    
    var isAnimating: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isAnimating {
                self.animateStroke()
                self.animateRotation()
            } else {
                self.shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you figured out how to deal with this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Hide the default spinning indicator by setting its `tintColor` to clear.

```
refreshControl.tintColor = .clear
```